# AWS Lambda GitLab CI/CD deployment package size is much bigger than deploy from my local environment

Tags: node.js, deployment, aws-lambda, gitlab, serverless-framework

I set up GitLab CI/CD for deploying a Node.js Lambda to AWS. However the zipped package size is 42.01MB when deployed by GitLab. But from my local PC the package size is only 10.72MB. Same command is used for deployment.

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` has the following setup

```yaml
image: node:latest

stages:
  - test
  - deploy_dev

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm test

dev:
    stage: deploy_dev
    before_script:
        - FAILURE_MESSAGE="Must define \$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and \$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. Add keys to $CI_PROJECT_URL/-/settings/ci_cd"
        - test -z "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" && echo $FAILURE_MESSAGE && exit 1
        - test -z "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" && echo $FAILURE_MESSAGE && exit 1
        - npm config set prefix /usr/local
        - npm install -g serverless
    script:
        - npm install
        - npm run deploy -- --stage dev --verbose
    environment: dev
    only: 
        - master
```

And the `package.json` is as follows

```json
{
  "name": "test app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "deploy": "serverless deploy"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.754.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "logplease": "^1.2.15",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.1",
    "serverless-offline": "^6.7.0",
    "serverless-offline-direct-lambda": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Output from GitLab:

```
$ npm install
added 725 packages, and audited 725 packages in 19s
found 0 vulnerabilities
$ npm run deploy -- --stage dev --verbose
> test-app@1.0.0 deploy
> serverless deploy "--stage" "dev" "--verbose"
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service test-app.zip file to S3 (42.01 MB)...
```

Local output

```
added 725 packages from 598 contributors and audited 725 packages in 12.388s

45 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities



Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service test-app.zip file to S3 (10.72 MB)...
```

It seems like the dev dependencies are NOT excluded although the logs says `Excluding development dependencies...`.

Does anyone have any ideas on why the package size is different?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- First of all please move the `aws-sdk` to dev dependencies. It is already installed in the AWS lambda container.
- Second, you may also use serverless plugin - [serverless-webpack](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) for more decreasing the size of lambda.

Besides that, I cannot notice anything significant what may cause the build size to be different :(

Comment: Yes moving the aws-sdk to dev dependencies is a good call! Thanks!